# Flutter DateTimeFormField Hint Text Color Doesn't Change

Tags: flutter

I have a big problem with DateTimeFormField on Flutter. I can't change hint, label, or default text style color change.

I already try this;

```
var textStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Hexcolor("#D8D8D8"),
  fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(42.0),
);

return DateTimeFormField(
  mode: widget.mode,
  label: widget.label,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Hexcolor("#F9F9F9"),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 20.0,
      top: 20.0,
      bottom: 5.0,
    ),
    prefixStyle: textStyle,
    hintStyle: textStyle,
    labelStyle: textStyle,
    border: defaultBorder,
    focusedBorder: focusedBorder,
    enabledBorder: enabledBorder,
  ),
  onDateSelected: widget.onDateSelected,
  //controller: widget.controller,
  //maxLines: maxLines,
  //obscureText: obscureText,
);
```

But color looks like this image :

[image]

How can I change the field default color?

Answer (score 0):

Never used the Hexcolor plugin, why don't you try with a basic Color like:

Colors.lightBlue

And then maybe other method with Hexa:

Color(0xFF8BC34A)

Comment: Hexcolor plugin is working as well on other text fields and I tried your answer but doesn't work :/